# Can a parameter be used to set the unit attribute for a component?

Tags: runtime-error, modelica, openmodelica, systemmodeler

So far, using Wolfram System Modeler 4.3 and 5.1 the following minimal example would compile without errors:

```
model UnitErrorModel
    MyComponent c( hasUnit = "myUnit" );

    block MyComponent
        parameter String hasUnit = "1";
        output Real y( unit = hasUnit );
    equation
        y = 10;
    end MyComponent;

end UnitErrorModel;
```

But with the new release of WSM 12.0 (the jump in version is due to an alignment with the current release of Wolfram's flagship Mathematica) I am getting an error message:

> Internal error: Codegen.getValueString: Non-constant expression:c.hasUnit

(Note: The error is given by `WSMLink'WSMSimulate` in Mathematica 12.0 which is running System Modeler 12.0 internally; here asking for the `"InternalValues"` property of the above model since I have not installed WSM 12.0 right now).

Trying to simulate the above model in OpenModelica [OMEdit v. 1.13.2 (64-bit)] reveals:

> SimCodeUtil.mo: 8492:9-8492:218]: Internal error Unexpected expression (should have been handled earlier, probably in the front-end. Unit/displayUnit expression is not a string literal: c.hasUnit

So it seems that to set the unit attribute I cannot make use of a variable that has parameter variability? Why is this - after all shouldn't it suffice that the compiler can hard-wire the unit when compiling for runtime (after all the given model will run without any error in WSM 4.3 and 5.1)?

EDIT:  From the [answer to an older question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52313716/5363743) I had believed that at least final parameters might be used to set the unit-attribute. Making the modification final (e.g. `c( final hasUnit = "myUnit" )` does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Does it simulate if you only use "Model Center" and "Simulation Center". `WSMLink'WSMSimulate` sounds like it is something related to the Matematica functionality.

Comment: @jrhodin I have removed WSM 12.0, but it would not compile there using "Model Center" and "Simulation Center" only, when I had it installed. I thought that at least a "final" parameter could be used to set a unit-attribute...

Comment: This works in Dymola, even in pedantic mode (which is more strict in checking if the code is conform with the Modelica specification).

Comment: @marco So it seems, that the example is not really violating Modelica specs?

Comment: Yes, from a Dymola user point of view it definitely does.

Comment: Does it make a difference whether you use `constant` instead of `parameter`?

Comment: @matth Yes, I just tried and it does not cause an error! A `parameter` would be more natural and convenient, but at least I just need marginal changes in my library. I am still not finding a reason from the specs for a `parameter` being a violation...

Comment: Yes, parameter would be nicer, and should probably work, but at least you have a workaround for now. You can also use `replaceable constant` and set the unit during instantiation.

Comment: And another idea that should work: `parameter String hasUnit = "1"  annotation (Evaluate=true);` Then it will be evaluated during compilation and becomes a string literal. But to change it, you will have to recompile! Also, you might want to send an email to Wolfram and ask why it does not work anymore.

Comment: @matth Sorry to mention this a bit late, but I cross posted on [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1684057); you may find WRI‘s answer there interesting. They have filed a proposal for the Modelica specs as they see `constants` more fitting for the unit attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been given [feedback on Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1684057) by someone from Wolfram MathCore regarding this issue:

> *You are correct in that it's not in violation with the specification,
>   although making it a constant makes more sense since you would
>   invalidate all your static unit checking if you are allowed to change
>   the unit after building the simulation. We filed an issue on the
>   specification regarding this* ([Modelica Specification Issue # 2362](https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/issues/2362)).

So, MatheCore is a bit *ahead of the game* in proposing a Modelica specification change that they have already implemented. ;-)

Note: That in Wolfram System Modeler (12.0) using the annotation `Evaluate = true` will not cure the problem (cf. the comment above by @matth).

As a workaround variables used to set the `unit` attribute should have *constant* *variability*, but can nevertheless by included in user dialogs to be interactively changed using `annotation(Dialog(group = "GroupName"))`.